# Render elements from array, which depend on whether the object has certain fields

Tags: reactjs

```
  <div className='row__posters'>
    {movies.map((movie) => (
      <img
        key={movie.id}
        onClick={() => handleClick(movie)}
        className={`row__poster ${isLargeRow && 'row__poster_big'}`}
        src={`${base_url}${
          isLargeRow ? movie.poster_path : movie.backdrop_path
        }`}
        alt={movie.title}
      />
    ))}
```

Ok i need render movie with only movie.poster_path and movie.backdrop_path fields to prevent mistakes u can see on pic [Dominic Toretto Family](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQ1Kv.png). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add check before you DOM img element like this

```
  <div className='row__posters'>
    {movies.map((movie) => 
      (movie.poster_path && movie.backdrop_path)?
      <img
        key={movie.id}
        onClick={() => handleClick(movie)}
        className={`row__poster ${isLargeRow && 'row__poster_big'}`}
        src={`${base_url}${
          isLargeRow ? movie.poster_path : movie.backdrop_path
        }`}
        alt={movie.title}
      />
       :null
    )}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just filter out the `movies` that do not have `poster_path` and `backdrop_path` before you render them.

```
<div className='row__posters'>
  {movies
    /* 
     * only keep movies that have both poster_path and backdrop_path
     * You may want to change this to OR condition depending on your logic
     */
    .filter(({ poster_path, backdrop_path }) => poster_path && backdrop_path)
    .map(movie => (
      <img
        key={movie.id}
        onClick={() => handleClick(movie)}
        className={`row__poster ${isLargeRow && 'row__poster_big'}`}
        src={`${base_url}${isLargeRow ? movie.poster_path : movie.backdrop_path
          }`}
        alt={movie.title}
      />
    ))}
</div>
```